# Why is this Ember.TextArea not binding to the controller content?

Tags: ember.js

In my index.html I have the following template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#with ChatApp.messagesController}}
      {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="content.message" rows="12" cols="70"}}
    {{/with}}
  </script>
```

My messages model looks like this

```
ChatApp.Message = Ember.Object.extend({
  message: null
});
```

My messages view and controller look like this

```
ChatApp.messagesView = Ember.View.extend({});

ChatApp.messagesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({                                                                                           
  content: [],
  text: '',
  sendMessage: function() {
    var newChatText = this.get('text');
    socket.emit('sendchat', newChatText);
  },
  updateChat: function(username, text) {
    var controller = this;
    var content = this.get('content');
    var newMessage = ChatApp.Message.create({ message: text });

    content.push(newMessage);
    console.log("update " + controller.get('content'));
    controller.set('content', content);
  }
});
```

I can see in the console.log that with each update another model object is being added to the content, yet the text area isn't being updated

Here is the jsFiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/eDfKJ/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do instead is to have a computed property which binds to the content and returns an aggregated string of all the messages, and I would bind the textarea to that.

Something like:

```
messages: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    var messages = "";

    ... loop the content and combine the messages string... 

    return messages;

}.property('content.@each')
```

and in your template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#with ChatApp.messagesController}}
      {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="content.messages" rows="12" cols="70"}}
    {{/with}}
  </script>
```

Comment: I think the property should be computed on 'content.@each', so it vill be reevaluated when inserting a new message.

Comment: wouldn't the valueBinding="messages" in this case? since content is the array and messages is our custom listener

Comment: you're welcome, and sorry for the direct edit, I believed you had to validate it before it would be active.

Answer (score 2):

It took a combined effort from both @ShaiRez and @sly7_7 so I wanted to include the FINAL working solution here

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#with ChatApp.messagesController}}
      {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="messages" rows="12" cols="70"}}                                                                                                            
    {{/with}}
  </script>

ChatApp.messagesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  text: '',
  sendMessage: function() {
    var x = this.get('text');
    socket.emit('sendchat', x);
  },    
  updateChat: function(username, text) {
    var controller = this;
    var newMessage = ChatApp.Message.create({ message: text });
    controller.content.pushObject(newMessage);
  },
  messages: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    var messages = "";
    for(i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {                                                                                                                                            
      messages += content[i].message                                                                                                                                                 
      messages += '\n';
    }
    return messages;
  }.property('content.@each')
  });
```

Comment: FYI, here is I think, an optimized version: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/U9j9f/ It does not iterate over the content at each change, but juste append the last message.
Note that you should use the get() method each you want access a property of an ember object.

Comment: nice improvement! now if only I could get you to reply to everything with an answer so I could get you some rep :)

Comment: Don't worry :), I'm not a rep hunter. The important thing is we learn something :)